# Convertin numbers from decimal to binary

Tags: android, kotlin

Don't judge strictly. I recently started studying kotlin and this is my first project.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button1.setOnClickListener {
        val t1:EditText=findViewById(R.id.editText1)
        var p:Int=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString())
        var f:String=""
        while (p != 0)
            p = p / 2
            f += p % 2
        f = f.reversed()
        val h = f.toIntOrNull()
        editText2.setText(h!!)
        }
    }
}
```

It slips out when I click on the button with this error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 6833
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:351)
>           at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4562)
>           at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:23)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)

Comment: Note that, due to the lack of curly braces, your code can be reduced to `var f = "0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow and to Android/Kotlin world!

The problem here is that your are calling TextView#setText with an integer. In android world this is used to pass resources references to string like `android.R.string.ok`, so you are trying to use a resource that is not defined.
To make it work, you need to pass `f` to setText:
`editText2.setText(f)`
Furthermore, as stated by JB Nizet in comment, you missed the brackets after while statement